# JS delete specific <li> element by addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a newbie in JS and DOM.

I'd like to delete a specific `li` item by clicking on its child delete button by using addEventListener(). I have found a few relevant solutions [like this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo), but I'm trying to come up with a more elegant solution.

```html
<ul>
    <li>Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

The following is a snipped JavaScript code I have tested but not had success with.

```js
function removeItem(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
}

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
```

Here is the full code:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

Array.from(ul.children).forEach( function(item) {
 appendDeleteBtnTo(item);
})

function appendDeleteBtnTo(element) {
 var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
 deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
 deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
 element.appendChild(deleteButton);
}

function lineThrough(e) {
 if (e.target.tagName === "LI") {
  e.target.classList.toggle("done");
 }
}

// =========== not working ====================================
function removeItem(e) {
 e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
// =============================================================

function inputLength() {
 return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
 ul.appendChild(li);
 input.value = "";
 appendDeleteBtnTo(li);
}

function addListAfterClick() {
 if (inputLength() > 0) {
  createListElement();
 }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
 if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
  createListElement();
 }
}


ul.addEventListener("click", lineThrough);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Shopping List</h1>
 <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
 <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
 <button id="enter">Enter</button>
 <ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
 </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should put the code in the question. Stackoverflow has the same snipplets which is the same functionality.

Comment: Problem is deleteButton you create is not the same as you add event listener too.... SHould be adding event when you create each button.

Comment: The code included in the question does not provide a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code to show where you are having a problem. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here on SO.

Comment: I appreciate all of you for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation by setting the event handler on the parent, and checking who is the actual target in the handler. This has two advantages:

1. You can add/remove list items without the need to attach event handlers to the added item.
2. You can easily combine the `delete` and line through functionalities in a single simple handler.

The event handler is added to the list (`ul`). Whenever the list or its children are click, the handler checks if the target is/inside a list item use `Element.closest()`. If no list item is found in the chain, the function terminates (`return`). If a list item is found (`target`), we check if the actual click target was the delete button. If it's the delete button the `target` is removed. If not, the the `done` class is added.

```
function listItemClickHandler(e) {
  const li = e.target.closest('li');

  if(!li) return;

  if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
    li.remove();
  } else {
    li.classList.toggle('done');
  }    
}
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

Array.from(ul.children).forEach(function(item) {
  appendDeleteBtnTo(item);
})

function appendDeleteBtnTo(element) {
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
  element.appendChild(deleteButton);
}

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  appendDeleteBtnTo(li);
}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function listItemClickHandler(e) {
  const li = e.target.closest('li');
  
  if(!li) return;
  
  if (e.target.matches('.delete')) {
    li.remove();
  } else {
    li.classList.toggle('done');
  }    
}

ul.addEventListener("click", listItemClickHandler);
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<p id="first">Get it done today</p>
<input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to come up with a more elegant solution

Since your callback is neither long nor elaborate, you can - rather than calling a named function - add an anonymous callback to your `.addEventListener()` method which contains the ES2015 `.remove()`:

```
.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.parentNode.remove(), false)
```

**Working Example:**

```js
const shoppingList = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
const shoppingListItems = [... shoppingList.getElementsByTagName('li')];

for (shoppingListItem of shoppingListItems) {

  let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.type = 'button';
  deleteButton.classList.add('deleteButton');
  deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete this';
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.parentNode.remove(), false);
  shoppingListItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
}
```

```css
li {
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.deleteButton {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Jello</li>
<li>Spinach</li>
<li>Rice</li>
<li>Birthday Cake</li>
<li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sure this isn't a `-1` answer.

Answer (score 2):

From your demo (truncated):

```
var deleteButton = document.createElement("button"); //<-- never inserted into DOM
//...
function appendDeleteBtnTo(element) {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    element.appendChild(deleteButton);
}
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
```

The problem is the deletion button you're assigning the event to is not the same as the deletion button you're ultimately appending to each `li` - that's being done quite separately inside `appendDeleteBtnTo()`. In fact, the one you're binding to is never actually inserted into the DOM.

You *could* bind the event inside that same function. Better, and more economical, would be to bind the event to the body (or at least some container) and thus 'delegate' the event, checking when it fires whether it applies to your specific circumstance.

We do that by checking what populated the `target` property of the event object.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if (!evt.target.matches('li > button')) return; //quit - click was not to li > button
    removeItem(evt); //remove li
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/60eymaj1/) We want to attach the event listener to each of the delete buttons that are being created.  See the modified fiddle.

```
function appendDeleteBtnTo(element) {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    element.appendChild(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Event Listener to each delete button where they have created.

function appendDeleteBtnTo(element) {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", removeItem); // add the event lisntener
    element.appendChild(deleteButton);
}

function removeItem(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
}
```

See the edited [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2qn1tv8s/)